# Find adjoint to integral operator from $H^1$ to $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators, integral-operators

Let $k(x, y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a kernel and $T: H^1(a, b) \to L_2(c, d)$
$$ T u(x) = \int\limits_{a}^{b} k(x, s) u(s) ds$$
Find the adjoint operator $T^*$.

It is easy to see the if $T: L_2(a, b) \to L_2(c, d)$, then $T^*$ can be expressed as
$$ T^*v(s) = \int\limits_{c}^{d} k(x, s) v(x) dx$$

However, here we need
$$ (Tu, v)_{L_2(c, d)} = (u, T^*v)_{H^1(a, b)} = (u, T^*v)_{L_2(a, b)} + (u', (T^*v)')_{L_2(a, b)}$$

I have tried to use the identity
$$ \int\limits_{a}^{b} uv dx = \int\limits_{a}^{b} u'v dx + \int\limits_{a}^{b} uv' dx $$

Then
$$ \int\limits_{c}^{d} \int\limits_{a}^{b} k(x, s) u(s) v(x) ds dx = 
\int\limits_{a}^{b} u(s) \left[ \int\limits_{c}^{d} k'_s(x, s) v(x) dx \right] ds +
\int\limits_{a}^{b} u'(s) \left[ \int\limits_{c}^{d} k(x, s) v(x) dx \right] ds $$

And it does not look like a form of adjoint operator...

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: The identity is wrong. It should read $$u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)=\int\limits_a^bu'v\,dx +\int\limits_a^buv'\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

The line
$$ (Tu, v)_{L_2(c, d)} = (u, T^*v)_{H^1(a, b)} = (u, T^*v)_{L_2(a, b)} + (u', (T^*v)')_{L_2(a, b)}$$
contains the answer. Define $z:=T^*v$. Then $z$ has to solve the equation
$$
(u, z)_{L_2(a, b)} + (u', z')_{L_2(a, b)}= (Tu, v)_{L_2(c, d)}
$$
for all $u\in H^1(a,b)$, or equivalently,
$$
\int_a^b z'(s)u'(s)+z(s)u(s) \ ds = \int_a^b \int_a^b k(x,s) u(s)v(x) \ dx \ ds .
$$
This is the weak formulation in $H^1$ of the boundary value problem
$$
-z''(x) + z(x) = \int_a^b k(x,s) u(s)\ ds
$$
with boundary conditions $z'(a)=z'(b)=0$.

Given $v$, one has to solve the integral equation or the boundary value problem to obtain $z:=T^*v$. Without further information about the problem this cannot be simplified. Note that the right-hand side of the boundary-value problem is equal to the expression of the adjoint operator of $T$ when considered as mapping from $L^2$ to $L^2$.

Comment: (+) There is a misprint in the last integral: should be $ds.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks, corrected.